# VSCode python refactoring: Rename symbol not working with attributes in class operator implementation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_attribute):
        self.my_attribute = my_attribute
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.my_attribute == other.my_attribute
```

Now rename the instance attribute: [`Symbol Rename`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol) (shortcut F2) on `my_attribute` (in `self.my_attribute` in line 3) and rename it e.g. to `my_attribute2`. You'll see that `other.my_attribute` won't be changed accordingly.

This also happens when adding type hints. The above code renaming should just work (because there is enough information for the refactoring tool to act correctly). But I even tried type hints (see [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)). Because of class name usage in definition of the class itself you have to use [Forward References](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references).

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_attribute):
        self.my_attribute = my_attribute
    
    def __eq__(self, other: "MyClass"):
        return self.my_attribute == other.my_attribute
```

or instead of Forward References using something of the future [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/):

```
from __future__ import annotations 

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_attribute):
        self.my_attribute = my_attribute
    
    def __eq__(self, other: MyClass):
        return self.my_attribute == other.my_attribute
```

But even with those type hints `Symbol Rename` does not work correctly.

Comment: This isn't a problem with your code, so there's not a lot we can do about it. FWIW PyCharm will offer to do the refactor in the first case, where it's not certain `other` is `MyClass`, and just do it automatically in the second and third where the type hint confirms that it is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, it's a problem with the python extension. But there is no appropriate tag for it yet, is it (like `visual-studio-code-python` or `visual-studio-code-extension-python`or `visual-studio-code-extensions-python`)?

Comment: I don't know if there's a tag; my point is this isn't an SO question. You need to report the issue to the maintainers of the tool that (fails to) provide the refactor.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I posted this here because it could be that it just is a configuration fault or other wrong usage. But according to you this is not the case. I now opened an issue on github for the python extension. Thank you for your comments .

Comment: You didn't show any configuration for it to be a fault in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no usage fault and seems to be a bug, according to jonrsharpe's comment an bug report is useful now, so I now opened an issue on github https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15922 .

*Edit*: The problem seems to be specific to python's [language server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) **jedi**, which is currently the standard on vscode python. Changing the language server (python.languageServer) to "microsoft" resolves the problem when using one of the type hint variants.

*Edit2*: I also tested pylance and it renames on all cases.

I got an answer of the maintainer of jedi ([see](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1769#issuecomment-819770134), i bolded the important parts):

> This is something that's simply not fixable. How would Jedi know that other is a MyClass? **This is simply a heuristic**. I know that we could theoretically assume this, but I'm not sure that's a great idea. I will definitely keep it in mind for the Rust version that I'm writing, but this will not happen in Jedi. Sorry. **There are a lot of cases where Python's dynamic nature is kind of a problem. And I chose to not use heuristics for all of these (because it makes Jedi also slower).**

Later he wrote (bolding done by me):

> > > I understand. Would it be possible to handle this like pycharm does? **Inquiring the user on such a case, to let him/her choose what to do** or do things like LSP not support such inquiring?
>
> **AFAIK the LSP protocol does not support this** (I have read it quite thoroughly). IMO that's the correct approach with such names. However it's still unlikely that Jedi will support this, because the **Jedi's API is probably not made for this**. **However I will keep it in mind for the next autocompletion project** that I'm doing :).

I think that makes it pretty clear.

Comment: This isn't an answer. I'd suggest deleting the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll wait for github feedback.

Comment: How does that change anything? You should at the very least delete this "answer", because it _isn't_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why? If someone else has this problem and finds this thread it seems appropriate to me that he/she knows that it probably not an error on his/her side and that it is currently being tracked on the issue on github.

Comment: A link to elsewhere is canonically [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Your GitHub issue might _lead to_ an answer, but it's not one. For that matter it's not really clear what you think on your end might have been the problem to begin with - your question was "I expected a third party piece of software to do something different", which is really between you and them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The answer is not your link's case. According to the [appropriate meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402002/34343455) this answer is an answer.